# PHP - How to echo profile page after form submit

Tags: php, profile

I am fairly new at PHP.  I am creating a staff management system for a client, and I want to create a unique link and echo the result after the user submits a new profile using a form.

In other words, on form submit, create unique page, and echo.

I’ve been googgling around but I don’t think I am using the right term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your looking for is URL parameters.

When you submit a form to a particular URL it sends all the form data via the URL parameters.

Depending on the type of submit `GET` or `POST` you can see the data in the URL or not.

To fetch the data

#### 1st page

```
<form method='POST' action='a.php'>
 <input type ='text' name='hi' />
</form>
```

#### 2nd Page

```
<?php
 echo $_POST['hi']; //this is how you access post and they are stored in a key value pair 
//with the key being the name. $_GET for get

?>
```

Comment: Thanks works fantastic. Does it work the same way if I want to echo the profile page from a table that I echo'd from mysql. In other words when the user click on a profile in an HTML table it redirects to user profile?

Comment: Yep you can use the `$_POST` just like a variable. So you would put it in your MySQL query and retrieve the correct output. Also, if the answer is correct please mark it as completed.